# USB drive "outruns" python script

Tags: python, command-line, usb, autorun

I am looking to create a usb drive that when inserted into a laptop will automatically run a python file (without any user interaction) which grabs their ip address and hostname and emails it to us in a text file. I know this seems sketchy, but it is for a pen test (I'm sure all of you are familiar with these kinds of tests)

I have the script already written, I just need to find a way to automatically run the script (regardless of what op system their running when somebody is dumb enough to put a usb drive into their computer... I have scavenged the web and found the "outrun.inf" ideas, but I know this does not work with all op systems...

My idea is to have it run command line commands when plugged into the laptop (which i can figure out later which command lines will work), but I am unsure if this is possible.. any ideas?

If their is another way you guys think could work to achieve what I am looking for, I am all ears!

Thanks all

Comment: It's not possible, at least with a USB mass storage device; security issues like this were closed long ago.

Comment: ok, is their another way you could think of that allows a python file to be ran as soon as they plug it in?

Comment: Get the user to knowingly install and run some software before the USB drive is connected.